# Faster way to check if elements in numpy array windows are finite

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have a very long NumPy array with `1_000_000_000` elements and I want to slide a `50` element window across the array and ask if all of the elements within the window are finite. If all elements within a `50` element window are all finite then return `True` (for that window), otherwise, if one or more elements within the `50` element window are not finite then return `False` (for that window). Continue this assessment until all windows are assessed. A nice way to do this is:

```
import numpy as np

def rolling_window(a, window):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)

    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = np.random.rand(100_000_000)  # This is 10x shorter than my real data
    w = 50
    idx = np.random.randint(0, len(a), size=len(a)//10)  # Simulate having np.nan in my array
    a[idx] = np.nan
    print(np.all(rolling_window(np.isfinite(a), w), axis=1))
```

However, this is slow when my array is of length `1_000_000_000`. Is there a faster way to accomplish this that also doesn't require a ton of memory?

Comment: what is the frequency/sparsity of infinite elements?  If they are sparse, you might do better taking much larger chunks first, subdividing them only if there is an infinite element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1:** Abuse strided windows directly into the `isfinite-mask` for the assignment -

```
def strided_allfinite(a, w):
    m = np.isfinite(a)
    p = rolling_window(m, w)
    nmW = ~m[:w]
    if nmW.any():
        m[:np.flatnonzero(nmW).max()] = False
    p[~m[w-1:]] = False
    return m[:-w+1]
```

Timings on given sample data :

```
In [323]: N = 100_000_000
     ...: w = 50
     ...: 
     ...: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.rand(N)  # This is 10x shorter than my real data
     ...: idx = np.random.randint(0, len(a), size=len(a)//10)  # Simulate...
     ...: a[idx] = np.nan

# Original soln
In [324]: %timeit np.all(rolling_window(np.isfinite(a), w), axis=1)
1.61 s ± 14.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [325]: %timeit strided_allfinite(a, w)
556 ms ± 87.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Approach #2**

We can leverage [`convolution`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) -

```
np.convolve(np.isfinite(a), np.ones(w),'valid')==w
```

**Approach #3**

With [`binary-erosion`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_erosion.html) -

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_erosion

m = np.isfinite(a)
out = binary_erosion(m, np.ones(w, dtype=bool))[w//2:len(a)-w+1+w//2]
```

Comment: In my test, `as_strided` is twice as fast as `convolve`.

Comment: I'm out of my coffee and can't get the logic behind `strided_allfinite`. But `np.all(strided_allfinite(a,w) == np.all(rolling_window(a,w), axis=1))` gives me `False`.

Comment: @QuangHoang That's a wrong way to check for equality. Try `np.array_equal(strided_allfinite(a, w), np.all(rolling_window(np.isfinite(a), w), axis=1))`. More coffee maybe? :)

Comment: I don’t understand, it might not be the best way, but certainly the correct way, given both arrays do not contain nan. Can you explain why.?

Comment: @QuangHoang Explain the logic you mean?

Comment: Explain why np.all (a==b) is not the correct way to check for equality.

Comment: @QuangHoang Well you should be doing `np.all(strided_allfinite(a,w) == np.all(rolling_window(np.isfinite(a), w), axis=1))`. Now, I need coffee.

Comment: If we know that `a` only contains 50% or leas of `np.nan`, would it be faster to start with an output array of all `True` values, find all of the indices for `np.nan`, use these as start indices, then add `m` to the start indices to get stop indices, and then set the output array at these start/stop index ranges to `False`?

Comment: @slaw Try that idea out and let me know the timings?

Comment: @Divakar The strided answer is still by far the fastest. I've been studying it closely and trying to understand what is happening since it wasn't obvious and, I must say, it is a really fascinating approach! Thank you